# Insert text after cursor pointer using selectionStart not working in vuejs

Tags: vuejs2

I have been trying to insert a text in vue-editor exactly where the cursor is at.I have tried "selectionStart" for getting position of cursor.But i got undefined.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <vue-editor ref="description" v-model="description"></vue-editor
    ><button type="button" @click="button_click"></button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { VueEditor } from "vue2-editor";
export default {
  components: {
    VueEditor,
  },
  name: "TemplateName",
  data() {
    return {
      description: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    button_click() {
      var tArea = this.$refs.description;
      var startPos = tArea.selectionStart;
      console.log(startPos); //getting undefined
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.$refs.description.quill.selection.savedRange.index